# Mailchimp issues with custom templates and Gmail IOS client

Tags: html-email, mailchimp, email-templates

**Edit: Added code sample and edited question**

I am having an issue with Mailchimp and Gmail for IOS client.

When I send a custom email template (cerberus-responsive) using Mailchimp the email arrives distorted in the Gmail for IOS client. If I send the same template through an email service like Putsmail, it arrives in Gmail for IOS just fine. I get similar results when I send the template to Litmus for testing. It looks fine in every client except Gmail for IOS. If I reply or forward, the problem seems to go away.

I have been removing sections of the code (two column, three column, background) to see what section is causing the issue, but so far I get the exact same results. I do not know a creative way to get the code unmodied from Gmail.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior or have a solution? I think it is something that Mailchimp is doing to the code. I contacted Mailchimp support, but they offer no support of custom templates and directed me to a troubleshooting document on the limitations of HTML Email.

**Output sample**

On the left is the expected result. On the right, the result I get with Gmail for IOS on an iPhone or in Litmus.

[image: Gmail client results]

**Code sample**

Body is limited to 30000 characters so I can't post the code directly.

- https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/main/cerberus-responsive.html

Comment: We can't test what is happening without the code, so, if you could post it that would be good. Only thing I can say from this position is that generally Gmail iOS is very temperamental and demands exactly right CSS. If one thing is wrong, it can delete the whole lot. Add this line after your other `<style>...</style>` blocks: `<style type="text/css">img {width:100%!important;height:auto!important;"}</style>` (yes you can have multiple style blocks)

Comment: @Nathan The code is too long for question. I posted a url instead. I am not sure of an easy way to get the code as it appears in the Gmail app.

Comment: Litmus looks fine, as you say. Mailchimp have locked down their 'add custom code' template area so I can't check it. You'll need to log a ticket with Mailchimp, as it appears they are 'validating' the code, and thus changing it.

Comment: @Nathan Unfortunately, Mailchimp offers zero support for custom templates. They will not disclose how templates are modified by them. I was hoping to figure out the issue and share a solution for anyone else facing the same problem. So far, no solution.

Comment: We could try a couple of things--when you insert the HTML into MailChimp, can you go back into the HTML and see if anything has changed? (Use, for example https://www.diffchecker.com/diff). Or, can you get the resultant HTML from Apple Mail or another email client (I say Apple Mail becaues that shouldn't change the HTML much)

Comment: @Nathan I added the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/u82zLm9h/2/ Mailchimp adds styles to the html tag, adds new meta tags and styles to meta tags.

Comment: Well there's no images in that code!

Comment: That template looks very similar to the one available in Dreamweaver under `Starter Templates`